# How to redirect media file http to https?

Tags: wordpress, apache, http, redirect, https

I have installed Let's Encrypt on my site. I have upload image it makes link https and it works fine. I have applied redirection rule in htaccess so it's not redirect http to https only in media file. I have use plugins and some hooks in functions.php but not get success.

Answer (score 0):

**For Redirect Purpose**
If you are using SSL certificates and you want to redirect all traffic from HTTP to HTTPS, then the plugin Force SSL is what you need.

**https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-ssl/**

**For Update URL http to https in db**

If you want to update URLs.You can use this,

**https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/**

Comment: Thanks for reply i have used valvet-blues but its not redirect media file http to https. can you give any other suggestion to achieve this goal.

Comment: do you have ssl certificate?

Comment: can you provide site url if its live.

Comment: http://govtjobstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/image00.png. I want this link to redirect to https. But unfortunately it not redirect using pluging and htacces rule

Comment: https://govtjobstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/AAI_4_4_4-300x229.png

Comment: Please clear cache of your browser or open into private window.

Comment: i have do this exercise but still not success

Comment: how did you check its load from http or https.In case you are load a differ protocol then it gives error in console